# How to migrate bug fixes in Released Managed package

Tags: managed-package, package, package-install, patch

I Created Released managed Package in DEV ORG, and Installing the Package in New DEV org and testing the Functionality.

I Encountered a issue in Installed org, Same issue has replicated in Development Org too. (It's a single line Code changes in Apex class and LWC).

Now i want to push this changes to Installed org without uninstalling the package, If we Uninstall all setup data will be removed.

Can you please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new released package version and update the Dev Org

It shouldn't make any Problems

Best, Nina